# Does a minor software update effect rooting method?

Tags: rooting, updates, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm a newcomer to Android, so I'm not very familiar with how rooting works on Android. In IOS minor updates such as going from 9.0 to 9.1 can sometimes result in a jailbreak method not working, I was wondering would that be the same if a Samsung S7 edge is updated with a minor security update from Samsung.

Comment: If you're rooted, you can't install an update; you'll get an error (unless you had used systemless root). Even if it's systemless root (Android 6+), you'd have to flash the old boot.img (which is automatically done by unrooting in SuperSU) inorder to successfully install the update; which ofcourse means you're unrooted and have to root again. If minor update, the same rooting method should work.

Comment: Also since it's Samsung, I recommend you search and read about "**Knox**". If it's tripped, you won't get updates I guess. Knox is tripped upon rooting (unlocking bootloader)

Comment: @GokulNC so basically like IOS I have to find a rooting method that doesnt trip **knox** for whichever particular version of the software I'm using if I'm going from Marshmallow to Nougat for instance but should be fine with any minor updates from Samsung?

Comment: Generally the rule of thumb is to never do any ota  updates while rooted unless you plan on starting from scratch. You can check out Xda forums as to whether or not there is a root for that version. I have a s7 edge as well and Samsung is a pain with updates. I wouldn't try the same root method until it has been verified with the security update. Could get you into a bootloop. Please post version/build number and carrier and I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

This ultimately depends on the manufacturer. Samsung is not at all friendly to the rooting of it's stock ROMs, and does lots of modification to it's Android ROMs, so I'd say it is a real possibility. If it were me, I would install Cynaogenmod instead if I were to root but still wanted OTA updates.

Google itself, which is where the baseline Android comes from, usually doesn't care all that much if people want to root their devices, and usually doesn't plug holes that allow rooting unless customer data is at risk as a result.

Answer (score 0):

for android apps on the market, rooting is like exploit the mobile system and get root privilege. Therefore, if the system gets updated, the update patch might fix the vulnerability, same attack approach might not be working again.

Answer (score 0):

Every update may contain security fixes (for ex. monthly security patches) and the security fix may address the exact exploit used by the root method.

So yes, even the smallest update may break rooting methods.

Answer (score -1):

Major updates of Android **may** include firmware updates/bootloader updates, which can change the process of rooting!